# scrollview inside fragment layout

Tags: android

How I use scrollview inside in activity main xml its consist with fragment layout consist with swipetorefreshlayout

activity main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    tools:context="com.example.prem.weatherapplication.activity.MainActivity">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/currentWeatherContainer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:name="com.example.prem.weatherapplication.fragment.CurrentWeatherFragment"

            />


</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment layout which is attached in activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    tools:context="com.example.prem.weatherapplication.fragment.WeatherFragment">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/rl"
                    >


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:id="@+id/city"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:layout_below="@id/city"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:id="@+id/country"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                            android:id="@+id/date"
                            android:layout_below="@id/country"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/condition"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:layout_below="@id/date"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="120dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:id="@+id/weatherImage"
                            android:layout_below="@id/condition"

                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/temp"

                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/weatherImage"
                            android:layout_below="@id/condition"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/humidity"

                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/weatherImage"
                            android:layout_below="@id/temp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/pressure"
                            android:layout_below="@id/humidity"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/weatherImage"

                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/weatherImage"
                            android:layout_below="@id/pressure"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
                            android:id="@+id/wind"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/ll"
                            android:layout_below="@id/wind"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/day_forecast"
                                    android:textSize="18sp"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:id="@+id/dailytext"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"


                                    />
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/ten_days"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:textSize="18sp"

                                    />

                        </LinearLayout>

                <ListView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_below="@id/ll"
                    />


                </RelativeLayout>





</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Thanks in advance..